# streaming content from my iPhone to Apple TV

Tags: iphone, dvr, appletv, fios

We recently purchased a vacation home in KY. Instead of paying for cable there, we got Apple TV. I have Fios Quantum service at my home in NJ. Supposedly I can watch what I DVR on the Fios app via my iPhone. Is it possible to mirror airplay that onto my TV in KY while it's recording so it's almost like watching TV live?

Comment: Airplay works if devices are on the same network. You could VPN into your home hetwork from the other home and then should work.

Comment: Take a look at [What topics can I ask about here](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)